# Add cookie to httpWebRequest.Headers

Tags: c#, cookies, httpwebrequest

My application does multiple GET and POST requests. For whatever reason on one of the POST requests the cookies are gone. So I extracted the cookie SID manually and saved it into a different variable. Now I want to add the cookie to headers, because cookieContainer is empty and I want to use my SID variable.
I tried:

```
request.Headers.Add("Cookie", "SESSID=" + SID ";");
```

But the cookie doesn't get added.. If I change "Cookie" to "Cookiee" then it gets added to the headers. **How can I add a cookie to the HttpWebRequest.Headers without using CookieContainer?** Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Cookie Collection is just a header. Obviously a meaningful one that browsers know what to do with. If you want the cookie to appear in the key/value pair where the key is 'Cookie' then you will have to add it to the Cookie Collection.

Adding it to the headers with the key of 'Cookie' does add it, but then the runtime is overwriting that value with the cookie's in the collection from the request which it rewrites out to the response.

Hope this helps.

Comment: when i am using cookie container to pass sesssion id and session name it is showing me that it is accessed by anonymous user but if iam using header then it showing that atleast my web service call is done my authenticated user but response is null. Can you help ?